# NumberFormatException when parsing a String to BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

My Code is :

```
String sql="insert into L_EC(AMOUNT)values(?)";

    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);


   for(int i=0;i<dtm.getRowCount();i++){
     BigDecimal nbr= parsing(dtm.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
     prst.setBigDecimal(1, nbr);
     prst.addBatch();
}
prst.executeBatch();
```

info: 
Column is of type `Currency`

```
private static BigDecimal parsing(String str) {
    String normalized="";
    if(str==null){
       normalized="0";
    }else{
     normalized = str.replaceAll("\\s", "").replace(',', '.');
    }
    return new BigDecimal(normalized);
```

problem is that when a cell from table contain NULL ,I get this message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:545)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
    at Vista.TCRCG.parse(TCRCG.java:130)
```

I think that the problem is on parsing method when the parser find a cell without a any text or value.

Comment: Please include the full exception stacktrace

Comment: I have include this function to my code  :
private static BigDecimal parse(String str) {
    String normalized="";
    if(str==null){
       normalized="0";
    }else{
     normalized = str.replaceAll("\\s", "").replace(',', '.');
    }
    return new BigDecimal(normalized);

Comment: Don't use comments, **edit** your question. And post the stacktrace with the full exception message.

Answer (score 1):

Your `parsing` method will throw that exception if `str` is an empty string (`""`) or a space (`" "`). You may need to do some extra checking, e.g.,

```java
if (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0) {
    normalized = "0";
```

Comment: After edit code with your answer ,it work perfectly,but when i want to insert data on database I got this message:

Exception in thread thread-0 java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception: 10

Comment: Finally, it works well, I have forgot a column name on query ,Thank you @Gord Thompson to your help